# All C# unit test dlls not executed on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ncover, nunit-2.5.9

I am trying to run unit tests from build file using **nunit-console-x86.exe**. I am reading the dlls from a nunit project file which has 33 entries. On my system all the tests are running, but when the same build file is running through Jenkins, only 15 dlls are picked up and run.

I have observed that after a few mins the following error comes on the cmd prompt -
system.outofmemoryexception' was thrown.

**This is my build file:**

```
<exec program="${ncover.exe}" failonerror="false"> 
  <arg value="Run"/> 
  <arg value="--project=${ncover.project}"/> 
  <arg value="--buildId=${ncover.build.id}"/> 
  <arg value="--"/> 
  <arg value="..\tools\NUnit\nunit-console-x86.exe"/>       
  <arg value="TestProject.nunit"/> 
  <arg value="/domain=Multiple"/> 
</exec>
```

**NUnit project:**

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="Debug" /> 
  <Config name="Debug" 
          configfile="TestA.dll.config" 
          binpathtype="Auto"> 
    <assembly path="TestA.dll" /> 
    <assembly path="TestB.dll" /> 
  </Config> 
  <Config name="Release" binpathtype="Auto" /> 
</NUnitProject>
```

Comment: What kind of projects are the DLLs (target system)? What is the ouptup of `nunit-console-x86.exe`? Are all projects using the same version of NUnit?

Comment: .NET dlls - target framework -v4.5.2. I do not see any error coming up. Default xml "TestResult.xml" is also not getting saved in the working directory. All projects use the same NUnit version - 2.5.9